# Web Service WCF publicado en una instancia IIS de Amazon no obtiene resultados de BD

Tags: webservice, iis, wcf

Espero puedan ayudarme, llevo días metido en lo mismo y no logro solucionar mi tema, tengo 2 servicios web WCF (todo está en un solo proyecto Refill.Facturacion.Service).
•   Servicio web Documento.svc
•   Servicio web Resumen.svc

Al realizar la publicación de los servicios (localmente) logro conectarme a la base de datos. Pero cuando publico mi servicio en una instancia IIS de Amazon (WebAPP Services), no obtengo ninguna fila seleccionada de mi tabla y este es el problema que no logro resolver.
Parte de mi arquitectura en AWS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siendo más especifico, la línea "SqlDataReader registros = cmd.ExecuteReader();" es donde tengo problemas, no sale error, pero “registros” no me trae ninguna línea afectada

```
try
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 1==========");
            sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        con = conex.f_getConexion();
        con.Open();
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 2==========");
            sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        cmd = new SqlCommand("pa_man_EmpresaEmisorKey_Lis", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@key", key);

        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 3==========");
            sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        SqlDataReader registros = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        Contribuyente obj = new Contribuyente();

        if (registros.Read())
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 4==========");
                sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
            }
            obj.IdContribuyente = Int32.Parse(registros["IdContribuyente"].ToString());
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 5==========");
                sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
            }
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 6==========");
            sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        registros.Close();
        con.Close();
        return obj;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(strPath))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("=============PASO 7==========");
            sw.WriteLine("===========fecha============= " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        throw;
    }
```

Si hubiera tenido problemas abriendo la conexión, la sentencia “con.Open();” hubiera originado un error (también probé con try catch y no entra al catch), por ello descarto que sea problema de conexión. Estos son los rastros que deja mi LOG (no entra al while)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Descarte que sea un problema de permisos de lectura y escritura de BD para mi usuario  IIS appPool ya que hice una publicación sencilla de una APP con la misma cadena de conexión de mi servicio “servicetest” y si logro leer registros, uso el mismo código para la conexión y llamado al SP.
De antemano, muchas gracias por el apoyo que falta me hace.

Comment: Podrías copiar el código en texto para que sea legible y poder ayudarte con tu duda.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto, siempre.

Comment: Ok amigo, disculpa la demora, ya puse el código